# Community detection: Any algorithm that assigns a person to multiple communities?

Tags: algorithm, graph, machine-learning, data-mining

I feel in some cases it is reasonable for a person to be assigned to multiple communities. For example in the science field a professor may work in multiple research areas. Is there an algorithm that assigns a person to multiple communities, or a "soft-labeling approach"?(e.g. a positive probability associated with a person belonging to any detected community)

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the setup? What data do you have to work with? What algorithms are you looking at so far?

Comment: I am working with scientific paper citation data. I've looked at things like minimum cuts etc. However I dont know of any algorithm that does a soft-labelling yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot. The term is "*Overlapping community detection*".

Take a look at this paper, for example, where you can find comparison of 14 such algorithms:

[Overlapping Community Detection in Networks: the State of the Art and Comparative Study [Xie, Kelley, Szymanski - 2011]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5813)

[BIGCLAM](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/bigclam-wsdm13.pdf), an algorithm presented by Yang and Leskovec is an interesting one, as it scales very well. It is available as part of [SNAP](https://snap.stanford.edu/snap/description.html).